# Printing out strings toggling through list of tuples...help?

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples which relate a given actor to other actors through the movies and co-stars:

For a given actor E ActE:

```
conn_list = [('m6', 'D ActD'), ('m3', 'B ActB'), ('m2', 'Kevin Bacon')]
```

So this says that:

```
E ActE was in a movie m6 with D ActD
D ActE was in a movie m3 with B ActB 
B ActB was in a movie m3 with Kevin Bacon
```

I'm just wondering how to print that out. I know how to toggle through a list and get the elements from the tuples. I am using a for loop to iterate through, but I dont know how to deal with the changing actors when print out the strings.

```
for connection in conn_list:
    print '%s was in %s with %s'(            , connection[0],            )
```

That is pretty much where I'm stuck at. I don't want to make multiple print statements since there might be too many movies and actors. Any ideas?

Comment: So are you trying to map actors to movies? An example output would be helpful, I think I answered the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your input does not match your format string, but this is what you want to do:

```
actor_name = "ActE"
conn_list = [('m6', 'D ActD'), 
             ('m3', 'B ActB'), 
             ('m2', 'Kevin Bacon')]

for con in conn_list:
     print "%s was in movie %s with %s" % (actor_name, con[0], con[1])
```

the format string will take the tuple and replace the `%s` with the element at that location, for example:

```
"%s likes %s" % ("bob", "apples")
```

will replace the first `%s` with `tuple[0]` and the second `%s` with `tuple[1]`

---

EDIT: While that will fix the problem in your question... Reading it again a few times, I think what you may want is something that groups actors in the same movie? but i am unsure.

Answer (score 1):

I think we're missing some contextual information? If `conn_list` is the connection list for the actor `E ActE` then presumably there's a variable which contains the string `E ActE`. Is that correct?

Serdalis has pointed out how you can use the `%` operator to print the message you want, but if you don't want to modify the structure of `conn_list` then you can use something like this:

```
current_actor = 'E ActE'
for connection in conn_list:
    print '%s was in %s with %s' % (current_actor, connection[0], connection[1])
    current_actor = connection[1]
```

When I run this with your `conn_list` I get:

```
E ActE was in m6 with D ActD
D ActD was in m3 with B ActB
B ActB was in m2 with Kevin Bacon
```

Even better would be to use the `format(...)` method of strings since the `%` operator is being phased out:

```
current_actor = 'E ActE'
print connection in conn_list:
    print '{0} was in {1} with {2}'.format(current_actor, connection[0], connection[1])
    current_actor = connection[1]
```

which produces the same output.

**Edit:** Serdalis edited their solution while I was writing this. The solution now uses the original form of `conn_list`.

Comment: I was asleep at the time :(, you are correct about `.format` though so +1 for that.